# Consistent answer to sci-kit learn GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How do I get a consistent answer using GridSearchCV in sci-kit learn?  I assume I'm getting different answers b/c different random numbers are causing the folds to be different each time I run it, though it is my understanding that the below code should solve this as `KFold` has `shuffle=False` by default.

```
clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid, cv=KFold(n, n_folds=10))
```

Comment: Some estimator have a ``random_state``, which could alter the outcome. ``SVC`` should be deterministic, as is ``KFold`` as you observed. Are you sure the rest of your script is deterministic?

Comment: Pretty sure it is.  Is the `predict_proba()` output of `SVC` deterministic?  If I remember correctly a cross-validation is run to estimate some parameter for determining the probabilities, but this is done in LIBSVM and I thought deterministic as well.  I ask b/c I'm not actually using `SVC` but a subclass I've created called `ProbSVC` which maps `predict` to `predict_proba`

Comment: It seems that `predict_proba()` is not deterministic...

Comment: Yes, the ``predict_proba`` does a 5-fold (I think) cross-validation to calibrate the probability output. Also, you should use the ``Scorer`` interface instead of subclassing imho ;)

Comment: Was waiting for the dev version to be released before using `Scorer`...I'm not pro enough yet to be using the bleeding edge :)

Comment: Sorry, my PhD got in the way of the release :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you identified in the comments, predict_proba is NOT deterministic!

But it does accept a random_state (as does KFold). I've found before that setting shuffle=False can lead to really poor results if your data were collected in a non-random order, so IMHO you're better off using shuffle and setting random_state to some number.

From [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

```
class sklearn.svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='rbf', degree=3, gamma=0.0, coef0=0.0, shrinking=True, probability=False, tol=0.001, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, verbose=False, max_iter=-1, random_state=None)
```

**random_state** : int seed, RandomState instance, or None (default)

The seed of the pseudo random number generator to use when shuffling the data for probability estimation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this parameter: random_state=7

Most things that have a random_state parameter leave it at None, which allows variation.

You must set it to some number to get consistent results.

I set it to 7 because I like 7.  Pick any number.

Answer (score 0):

For `GridSearchCV`, it's also important to set `numpy.random.seed` to get reproducible results. This must be done in addition to setting `random_state` or `seed` in the estimator.

```
numpy.random.seed(42)
```